# how to hide this notice

Tags: javascript, php, session

i just want to ask how to hide this below notice.

Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\secxampp\htdocs\MKSFINALASD\web\check.php on line 2

my first code is check1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    include ("preorder.php");
else
    include("login.php");
?>
```

this is my sec code check.php.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    include ("top2.php");
else
    include("top.php");
?>
```

the problem start when i click book now button in this code

```html
<!--
Author: W3layouts
Author URL: http://w3layouts.com
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<title>Free Web-Hosting Website Template | Website-Builder :: w3layouts</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("check.php");
?>
<div class="blue-bar">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="host-content">
    <div class="plans-masthead" style="overflow:visible;">
      <h2>CAR GRAB <em>Service</em></h2>
         <ol>
            <li>Easy To Make A Booking </li>
            <li>Fast Respond Within 15 Minutes</li>
            <li>Dadicated driver with license and certificate</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
     <div class="linux-banner">
        <img src="images/car.gif" style="top:15px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="row-indent">
     <h2 class="h2-subheading">Select Your <em>DESTINATION</em></h2>
 </div>
<div class="host-main">
 <div class="plans-columns-wrp">
      <div class="grids-hosting">
        <ul class="plan-list us_plan ">
        <form name="hostingplan" id="hostingplan_4" method="POST">
      <img src="images/download.jpg" style="top:15px;" />
         <li class="p-name"><span class="pl-title">KTM&nbsp;<span style="border-left: 2px ridge  #2396FF; padding:4px 0;">&nbsp;TANGJUNG MALIM<sub></sub></span><b></b></span></li>
         <li class="p-feat">Web Space - 3 GB</li>
         <li class="p-feat1">Get a base Website</li>
         <li class="p-feat">Unlimited  Data Transfer</li>
          <li class="p-dropdown">
              <select name="duration">
                  <option value="1">  1  Year at <span class=WebRupee>$.</span> 50/month </option>
              </select>
          </li>
         <li class="p-button"><a class="txt-button" href="check2.php">BOOK NOW</a></li>
         </form>
  </ul>
        <ul class="plan-list us_plan ">
        <form name="hostingplan" id="hostingplan_4" method="POST">
      <img src="images/baru.jpg" style="top:15px;" />
         <li class="p-name"><span class="pl-title">NEW&nbsp;<span style="border-left: 2px ridge  #2396FF; padding:4px 0;">&nbsp;CAMPUS<sub></sub></span><b></b></span></li>
         <li class="p-feat">Web Space - 3 GB</li>
         <li class="p-feat1">Get a base Website</li>
         <li class="p-feat">Unlimited  Data Transfer</li>
          <li class="p-dropdown">
              <select name="duration">
                  <option value="1">  1  Year at <span class=WebRupee>$.</span> 50/month </option>
              </select>
          </li>
         <li class="p-button"><a class="txt-button" href="check2.php">Buy Now</a></li>
         </form>
  </ul>
  <ul class="plan-list us_plan ">
        <form name="hostingplan" id="hostingplan_4" method="POST">
      <img src="images/lama.jpg" style="top:15px;" />
         <li class="p-name"><span class="pl-title">OLD&nbsp;<span style="border-left: 2px ridge  #2396FF; padding:4px 0;">&nbsp;CAMPUS<sub></sub></span><b></b></span></li>
         <li class="p-feat">Web Space - 3 GB</li>
         <li class="p-feat1">Get a base Website</li>
         <li class="p-feat">Unlimited  Data Transfer</li>
          <li class="p-dropdown">
              <select name="duration">
                  <option value="1">  1  Year at <span class=WebRupee>$.</span> 50/month </option>
              </select>
          </li>
         <li class="p-button"><a class="txt-button" href="check2.php">Buy Now</a></li>
         </form>
  </ul><br><br><br>
        <ul class="plan-list us_plan plan-featured">
      <form name="hostingplan" id="hostingplan_5" method="POST">
          <img src="images/images.jpg" style="top:15px;" />
          <li class="p-name2"><span class="pl-title">TOWN&nbsp;<span style="border-left: 2px ridge  rgb(240, 180, 94); padding:4px 0;">&nbsp;TANGJUNG MALIM<sub></sub></span><b></b></span></li>
          <li class="p-feat">Web Space - 20 GB</li>
          <li class="p-feat1">Everything need your site</li>
          <li class="p-feat">Depending on your Business</li>
                <li class="p-dropdown">
              <select name="duration">
                  <option value="1">  1  Year at <span class=WebRupee>$.</span> 500.00/month </option>
              </select>
          </li>
          <li class="p-button"><a class="txt-button" href="check2.php">Buy Now</a></li>
          </form>
   </ul>
      </div>
   
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        display_preferred_server_location("us");
        var left= ($(".plans-columns-wrp").width()/2 )-($(".server_loc_tabs").width()/2);
        $(".server_loc_tabs").css('left', left + 'px');

        $(".server_loc_tabs li").click( function(){
            $(".server_loc_tabs li").removeClass('sel');
            $(this).addClass('sel');
            $('.sel_tab').remove();
            $(this).append("<div class='sel_tab'></div>");
            $('#plans-container input[type=radio]').removeAttr("checked");
        })

        $('.country_specific_tabs li').each(function() {
            add_event_to_tabs($(this).attr('country'));
        });
    });

    function add_event_to_tabs(country){
        $(".tab_" + country).click( function(){
            var sel_tab_left=($(this).outerWidth()/2 );
            $(".server_loc_tabs li .sel_tab").css('left', sel_tab_left + 'px');
            var location = $(this).attr('country').toLowerCase();
            $('.plan-list').hide();
            $('.' + location + '_plan').show();
        })
    }

    function display_preferred_server_location(location){
        $('.plan-list').hide();
        $(".tab_" + location.toUpperCase()).addClass('sel').append("<div class='sel_tab'></div>");
        $('.' + location + '_plan').show();
        $('#' + location.toUpperCase() + '_plan_check').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
include("bottom.html");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

then the notice will appear in this site.

```html
<!--A Design by W3layouts
Author: W3layout
Author URL: http://w3layouts.com
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<title>Free Web-Hosting Website Template | Login :: w3layouts</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("check.php");
?>
<div class="bulk-domain">
 <div class="content">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="login_form">
      <div class="login_form_left">  
        <h3>Sign in to make a booking!</h3> 
       <form method="post" action="loginproc.php">
      <table>
      <tbody><tr><td><div><label>Username <span class="astrix">*</span></label><input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username"></div>
      <div><label>Password <span class="astrix">*</span></label><input type="password" value=""name="password" id="password"></div></td></tr>
      <tr><td><label style="display:inline">Remember Me</label><input type="checkbox" value=""></td><td><span><a href="#">Forgot Password ?</a></span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input name="Checkout" type="submit" class="uiButton" value="Sign In"></td></tr>
      </tbody></table>   
      </form>
     </div>
     <div class="login_form_right">
      <h3>Don't have a account?</h3>
    <div><a href="create-account.php"><button type="submit" name="submit" class="uiButton" id="new_submit">Create an Account in 5 minutes</button></a></div>
     </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
<?php
include("bottom.html");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't hide it. Fix it.

Comment: you are starting session multiple times, it is needed only once.

Comment: write @session_start

Comment: Where do you set a value into the `$_SESSION['username']` as I cannot see anywhere in the code you shows us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all `session_start()` with the following check:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: Cannot think why this would fix anything

Comment: Might be more useful to ask where does OP set a value into the `$_SESSION['username']` as I cannot see anywhere in the code he shows us

Answer (score 0):

try this,

in check.php

Replace `session_start();` with this code

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
}
```

I suggest you to use [ob_start();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) before starting any sesson varriable.

Comment: Cannot think why this would fix anything

Comment: Might be more useful to ask where does OP set a value into the `$_SESSION['username']` as I cannot see anywhere in the code he shows us